# Ayuda con html y css

Tags: html, css, html5

Que tal amigos, verán trato de que la etiqueta body sea responsive...

y el footer siempre aparezca al final (bottom:0;)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
header{
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background-color:red;

}
nav{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;

}

body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;

}

.clear {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

footer{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;

}

</style>
</head>

<header>
</header>

<div class="clear"></div>

<nav>
</nav>

<div class="clear"></div>

<body>

</body>

<div class="clear"></div>

<footer>

</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola para que algunas de tus etiquetas sean responsive debes hacer uso de funciones com estas

```
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width:903px) {
    .buysellads.buysellads-demo {
        top: 55px;
        right: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        z-index: 1000
    }
}
```

que te ayudan.
Pero te aconsejo framework CSS muy potentes para eso como Materialize y Bootstrap que se encargaran de que tu página sea super responsive

Comment: La estructura de las páginas web es <html><head></head><body></body></html> , No lo que tienes montado ahí que está el body por medio el footer después del body etc...